# JQuery add class. By searching for all elements with the same class

Tags: jquery, html

Once I try to add an element by searching for a class it won't work.

This is what i've tried before:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var btn = $('#nightmode-btn');

  btn.click(function() {
    $('.white').addClass('.black').removeClass('.white');
  });

});
```

Comment: In jquery, you can also just put the variable in the statement like so: `$('#nightmode-btn').click(function() {
        $('.white').addClass('black').removeClass('white');
      });`. So you don't need to declare it before hand - neater code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addClass` and `removeClass` accepts classname(s) as argument and not selector. Use:

```
$('.white').addClass('black').removeClass('white');
```